# Marketing Cloud - custom subscription center

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, marketing-cloud-connect

There is a requirement to build a custom subscription center with SSJS.
PersonHasOptedOutOfEmail field in Account_Salesforce and changes to All
Subscribers status field reflect this field.

Does anyone have any examples?

The key is to change Opt-In / Opt-Out status for All Subscribers.

Thank you!

Comment: Do yourself and the community a favor and try building it...then update your question with details about where you're stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various resources where you can find how this can be achieved. When using SSJS you can send a request to the SOAP-API to unsubscribe for example.

**Basically the SOAP-Envelope would look like this:**

```
<soap-ENV:Body>
    <ExecuteRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
        <Requests>
            <Name>LogUnsubEvent</Name>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>SubscriberID</Name>
                <Value>123456</Value>
            </Parameters>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>SubscriberKey</Name>
                <Value>Key for username@example.com</Value>
            </Parameters>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
                <Value>help@example.com</Value>
            </Parameters>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>JobID</Name>
                <Value>18099</Value>
            </Parameters>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>ListID</Name>
                <Value>17914</Value>
            </Parameters>
            <Parameters>
                <Name>BatchID</Name>
                <Value>0</Value>
            </Parameters>
        </Requests>
    </ExecuteRequestMsg>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

**These resources should be helpful:**

- [SSJS Syntax Guide: Unsubscribe](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/subscriber_server_side_javascript_functions/unsubscribe/)
- [Unsubscribe and Log an UnsubEvent with a LogUnsubEvent Execute Call](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call.htm?search_text=LogUnsubEvent)
- [Create a Custom Profile Center with AMPscript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/creating_a_custom_profile_center_using_ampscript_and_the_soap_api.htm?search_text=Custom%20Profile%20Center)
- [API Starter Kit: SOAP Envelopes (zip-file)](http://help.marketingcloud.com/globalassets/documentation/apistarterkits/soapv3.zip)

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a processing page that handles AJAX calls from a preference centre. It performs all the operations you mention, I think. It updates the Contact.HasOptedOutOfEmail field in CRM, but from memory, updating this field also updates the Account.PersonHasUpdatedFromEmail field when you're dealing with a Person Account.

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("Core","1");

  var lid = 31; // All Subscribers

  //These variables are available from the "context"
    var contactId = Attribute.GetValue("_subscriberkey");
    var email = Attribute.GetValue("emailaddr");

  /* These variables have been made available through the passing in query string */
    var jid = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("jid");
    var bid = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("bid");

  Write(Stringify(processRequest()));

  function processRequest(){
    Platform.Response.SetResponseHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:","*");

    var response;

    if (Platform.Request.Method == "GET"){

      var profile =   {
                        "subscriberid":   Attribute.GetValue("subscriberid"),
                        "subscriberkey":  Attribute.GetValue("_subscriberkey"),
                        "email":          Attribute.GetValue("emailaddr"),
                        "emailoptout":    null,
                        "lists":          []
                      };

      try{
        profile.emailoptout = getEmailOptOut(profile.subscriberkey);
      }
      catch (err){
        response =  {
                      "code":404,
                      "message":"Unable to locate your record. Please try again later"
                    };

        return response;
      }

      try{
        var lists = getLists();
        profile.lists = getListMembership(contactId, lists)
      }
      catch (err){
        response =  {
                      "code":405,
                      "message":"Unable to locate your record. Please try again later" + Stringify(err)
                    };

        return response;
      }

      response =  {
                    "code":     200,
                    "message":  "OK",
                    "profile":  profile
                  };
    }
    else if (Platform.Request.Method == "POST"){
      var action = Platform.Request.GetQueryStringParameter("a");
      var payload = Platform.Request.GetPostData();

      if (action == "u"){
        response = logUnsub();
      }
      else if (action == "p"){
        response = updatePreferences(payload);
      }
      else {
        // Action no supported - not p or u
        response =  {
                      "code":406,
                      "message":"Unsupported action."
                    };
      }
    }
    else {
      // Method no supported
      response =  {
                    "code":403,
                    "message":"Unsupported method."
                  };
    }

    return response;
  }


  function getEmailOptOut(ContactId){
    Variable.SetValue("@ContactID",ContactId);
        // BEGIN Nested AMPScript
        </script>
        %%[

            /* Contact attributes from Sales Cloud */
            SET @RSContacts = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","HasOptedOutOfEmail", "Id", "=", @ContactID)

      IF RowCount(@RSContacts) > 0 THEN
        SET @EmailOptOut = Field(Row(@RSContacts,1),"HasOptedOutOfEmail")
      ENDIF

        /* END Nested AMPScript */
        ]%%
        <script language="JavaScript" runat="server">

        return(Variable.GetValue("@EmailOptOut"));
    }

  function getLists(){
    var publicLists = [];
    var lists = List.Retrieve({Property:"ListClassification",SimpleOperator:"equals",Value:"PublicationList"});
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
        if(lists[i].Type=="Public"){
          var list =  {
                      "id":           lists[i].ID,
                      "name":         lists[i].ListName,
                      "description":  lists[i].Description
                    };
          publicLists.push(list);
        }
    }
    return publicLists;
  }

  function getListMembership(subscriberKey,lists){

    // Do an API retrieve on ListSubscribers
    var rr = Platform.Function.CreateObject("RetrieveRequest");

    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "ObjectType", "ListSubscriber");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "ListID");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(rr, "Properties", "Status");

    // Define filter based on subscriberkey
    var sfp1 = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp1, "Property", "SubscriberKey");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp1, "SimpleOperator", "equals");
    Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(sfp1, "Value", subscriberKey);


    // And ListID in this filter
    var sfp2 = Platform.Function.CreateObject("SimpleFilterPart");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp2, "Property", "ListID");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(sfp2, "SimpleOperator", "IN");

    // Loop through lists adding listid to filter
    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(sfp2, "Value", lists[i].id + ""); //Needs to be a string added as value
    }

    //Adding two Simple filters together to create a Complex filter
    var cfp = Platform.Function.CreateObject("ComplexFilterPart");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "LeftOperand", sfp1);
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "LogicalOperator", "AND");
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(cfp, "RightOperand", sfp2);

    //Add the Complex filter to the RetrieveRequest
    Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(rr, "Filter", cfp);

    var retrieveStatus = [0, 0, 0];
    var retrieveResult = Platform.Function.InvokeRetrieve(rr, retrieveStatus);

    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
      var status = 'Active';
      for(var r in retrieveResult) {
        if(lists[i].id == retrieveResult[r].ListID && retrieveResult[r].Status == "Unsubscribed"){
          status = "Unsubscribed"
        }
      }

      lists[i].status = status;
    }

    return lists;
  }

  function logUnsub(){
        // Server-Side JavaScript API Code to unsub in Marketing Cloud and show in reporting
        var lue, lue_prop, Response;
    Variable.SetValue("@ContactID",contactId);

        try {
            lue = Platform.Function.CreateObject("ExecuteRequest");
            Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue,"Name","LogUnsubEvent");

            lue_prop = Platform.Function.CreateObject("APIProperty");
            Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Name", "SubscriberKey");
            Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Value", contactId);
            Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(lue, "Parameters", lue_prop);

            lue_prop = Platform.Function.CreateObject("APIProperty");
            Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Name", "JobID");
            Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Value", jid);
            Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(lue, "Parameters", lue_prop);

            lue_prop = Platform.Function.CreateObject("APIProperty");
            Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Name", "ListID");
            Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Value", lid);
            Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(lue, "Parameters", lue_prop);

            lue_prop = Platform.Function.CreateObject("APIProperty");
            Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Name", "BatchID");
            Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Value", bid);
            Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(lue, "Parameters", lue_prop);

            lue_prop = Platform.Function.CreateObject("APIProperty");
            Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Name", "Reason");
            Platform.Function.SetObjectProperty(lue_prop, "Value", "Profile Center Unsubscribe");
            Platform.Function.AddObjectArrayItem(lue, "Parameters", lue_prop);

            var statusAndRequest = [0,0];

            Response = Platform.Function.InvokeExecute(lue, statusAndRequest);

            //Check return code - 12012 denotes subscriber is already unsubscribed
            if (!Response[0].ErrorCode == 0 && !Response[0].ErrorCode == 12012){
        return  {
                  "code":501,
                  "message":"Sorry. We were unable to complete your request at this time. Please try again later."
                };
            }
        }
        catch (err) {
      return  {
                "code":502,
                "message":"Sorry. We were unable to complete your request at this time. Please try again later."
              };
        }

        try {
            // BEGIN Nested AMPScript
            </script>
            %%[
                SET @result = UpdateSingleSalesforceObject("Contact",@contactId,"HasOptedOutOfEmail","1")
            /* END Nested AMPScript */
            ]%%
            <script language="JavaScript" runat="server">
        }
        catch (err) {
            // Do nothing - the subscriber has already been unsubscribed in Marketing Cloud
            // SFDC Email Opt Out - nice to have
        }
    return  {
              "code":200,
              "message":"Thank you. You will receive no further email communication from Lendi."
            };
    }//function logUnsub


  function updatePreferences(payload){

    try{
      payload = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(payload);
    }
    catch (err){
      return  {
                "code":601,
                "message":"Sorry. We were unable to update your details at this time. Please try again later."
              };
    }

    if(payload.length > 0){
      var sub = {
                    "SubscriberKey": contactId,
                    "Lists": []
                };

      for (var i = 0; i < payload.length; i++) {
        var list = payload[i];

        sub.Lists.push({"Status": list.status, "ID": list.listid, "Action": "Upsert"});
      }

      try {
        var subObj = Subscriber.Init(contactId);
        var status = subObj.Upsert(sub);

        return  {
                  "code":200,
                  "message": "Thank you. Your preferences have been updated successfully."
                };
      }
      catch (err) {
        return  {
                  "code":604,
                  "message":"Sorry. We were unable to update your details at this time. Please try again later."
                };
      }

    }

  }
</script>
```